# How to apply groupby and transpose in Pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
 'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3','READ_1','READ_5','READ_6','READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
 'val' :[5,6,7,11,5,7,16,12,13,56,32,13,45,43,46], 
 })
```

My above input dataframe looks like this

[image]

Though the code below works fine(thanks to Jezrael) in Python pandas, when I apply this to real data (more than 4M records), it runs for a long time. So I was trying to use `pyspark` . Please note I already tried `Dask`,`modin`,`pandarallel` which are equivalent to pandas for large scale processing but didn't help either. What the below codes does is `it generates the summary statistics for each subject for each reading`. You can have a look at the expected output below to get an idea

```
df_op = (df.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
        .describe()
        .unstack()
        .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
        .reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0))
df_op.columns = df_op.columns.map('_'.join)
df_op = df_op.reset_index()
```

Can you help me achieve the above operation in pyspark? When I tried the below, it threw an error

```
df.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
```

For example - subject_id = 1 has 4 readings but 3 unique readings. So we get 3 * 8 = 24 columns for subject_id = 1. Why 8? Because it's `MIN,MAX,COUNT,Std,MEAN,25%percentile,50th percentile,75th percentile`. Hope this helps

When I started off with this in pyspark, it returns the below error

> TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to do? The code is not a good reference since it's not working

Comment: @pissall - No, its a working code. can you try once again? What I would like to do is get the `summary statistics for each subject for each reading`

Comment: @pissall - Updated with an example for `subject_id = 1` in the post. Let me know if you have any more doubts

Comment: What all summary statistics do you want? You will have to code aggregate using groupby

Comment: Like `Min,Max,Avg,Count,25th percentile, 75th percentile`. As you can see, I was able to do this in pandas but not in pyspark. Can you help me?

Comment: I already tried `groupby`. If you see my attempt for `pyspark` in code above, you will see that I have an error. I just like to reproduce the same pandas code in pyspark

Comment: I will resolve it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to groupby and get the statistics for each reading first, and then you make a pivot to get an expected outcome

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

agg_df = df.groupby("subject_id", "readings").agg(F.mean(F.col("val")), F.min(F.col("val")), F.max(F.col("val")),
                                                    F.count(F.col("val")),
                                                    F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.25)').alias("quantile_25"),
                                                    F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.75)').alias("quantile_75"))
```

This will give you the following output:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|subject_id|readings|avg(val)|min(val)|max(val)|count(val)|quantile_25|quantile_75|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|         2|  READ_1|     5.0|       5|       5|         1|          5|          5|
|         2|  READ_5|     7.0|       7|       7|         1|          7|          7|
|         2|  READ_8|    12.0|      12|      12|         1|         12|         12|
|         4| READ_08|    43.0|      43|      43|         1|         43|         43|
|         1|  READ_2|     6.0|       6|       6|         1|          6|          6|
|         1|  READ_1|     6.0|       5|       7|         2|          5|          7|
|         2|  READ_6|    16.0|      16|      16|         1|         16|         16|
|         1|  READ_3|    11.0|      11|      11|         1|         11|         11|
|         4| READ_11|    32.0|      32|      32|         1|         32|         32|
|         3| READ_10|    13.0|      13|      13|         1|         13|         13|
|         3| READ_12|    56.0|      56|      56|         1|         56|         56|
|         4| READ_14|    13.0|      13|      13|         1|         13|         13|
|         4| READ_07|    46.0|      46|      46|         1|         46|         46|
|         4| READ_09|    45.0|      45|      45|         1|         45|         45|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Using groupby `subject_id` if you pivot `readings`, you will get the expected output:

```
agg_df2 = df.groupby("subject_id").pivot("readings").agg(F.mean(F.col("val")), F.min(F.col("val")), F.max(F.col("val")),
                                                         F.count(F.col("val")),
                                                         F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.25)').alias("quantile_25"),
                                                         F.expr('percentile_approx(val, 0.75)').alias("quantile_75"))

for i in agg_df2.columns:
    agg_df2 = agg_df2.withColumnRenamed(i, i.replace("(val)", ""))
agg_df2.show()

+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|subject_id|READ_07_avg(val)|READ_07_min(val)|READ_07_max(val)|READ_07_count(val)|READ_07_quantile_25|READ_07_quantile_75|READ_08_avg(val)|READ_08_min(val)|READ_08_max(val)|READ_08_count(val)|READ_08_quantile_25|READ_08_quantile_75|READ_09_avg(val)|READ_09_min(val)|READ_09_max(val)|READ_09_count(val)|READ_09_quantile_25|READ_09_quantile_75|READ_1_avg(val)|READ_1_min(val)|READ_1_max(val)|READ_1_count(val)|READ_1_quantile_25|READ_1_quantile_75|READ_10_avg(val)|READ_10_min(val)|READ_10_max(val)|READ_10_count(val)|READ_10_quantile_25|READ_10_quantile_75|READ_11_avg(val)|READ_11_min(val)|READ_11_max(val)|READ_11_count(val)|READ_11_quantile_25|READ_11_quantile_75|READ_12_avg(val)|READ_12_min(val)|READ_12_max(val)|READ_12_count(val)|READ_12_quantile_25|READ_12_quantile_75|READ_14_avg(val)|READ_14_min(val)|READ_14_max(val)|READ_14_count(val)|READ_14_quantile_25|READ_14_quantile_75|READ_2_avg(val)|READ_2_min(val)|READ_2_max(val)|READ_2_count(val)|READ_2_quantile_25|READ_2_quantile_75|READ_3_avg(val)|READ_3_min(val)|READ_3_max(val)|READ_3_count(val)|READ_3_quantile_25|READ_3_quantile_75|READ_5_avg(val)|READ_5_min(val)|READ_5_max(val)|READ_5_count(val)|READ_5_quantile_25|READ_5_quantile_75|READ_6_avg(val)|READ_6_min(val)|READ_6_max(val)|READ_6_count(val)|READ_6_quantile_25|READ_6_quantile_75|READ_8_avg(val)|READ_8_min(val)|READ_8_max(val)|READ_8_count(val)|READ_8_quantile_25|READ_8_quantile_75|
+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|         1|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            6.0|              5|              7|                2|                 5|                 7|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            6.0|              6|              6|                1|                 6|                 6|           11.0|             11|             11|                1|                11|                11|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|
|         3|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|            13.0|              13|              13|                 1|                 13|                 13|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            56.0|              56|              56|                 1|                 56|                 56|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|
|         2|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            5.0|              5|              5|                1|                 5|                 5|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|            7.0|              7|              7|                1|                 7|                 7|           16.0|             16|             16|                1|                16|                16|           12.0|             12|             12|                1|                12|                12|
|         4|            46.0|              46|              46|                 1|                 46|                 46|            43.0|              43|              43|                 1|                 43|                 43|            45.0|              45|              45|                 1|                 45|                 45|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            32.0|              32|              32|                 1|                 32|                 32|            null|            null|            null|              null|               null|               null|            13.0|              13|              13|                 1|                 13|                 13|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|           null|           null|           null|             null|              null|              null|
+----------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Just use the second step bro. First step is demonstration of how to get statistics.

Comment: Oh yeah. Just noticed the dataframe name

Comment: Actually am trying to view the output using `agg_df2.show()`. Unable to verify the `show` output because of null values due to my real data.Is it possible to view this in a nice table form like a pandas dataframe? I tried this `result_pdf = agg_df2.select("*").toPandas()` but it's running for a long time.

Comment: And it resulted in error finally. I mean the display. Might be due to large dataset? How can I see the output in a table form like shown in the expected output section?

Comment: Yes, `toPandas()` on a large dataset is very expensive because it will bring all your data on the executor. Check executor memory for the same.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyother way to view this?

Comment: @SSMK A more efficient way to store this is without pivot. Like in the first step. It will be easier to visualize as well .If you have columns for all readings you're unnecessarily increasing the memory consumption. There are so many columns and so many null values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201244/discussion-between-ssmk-and-pissall).